# react router changes navigation but does not render page using redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have got a simple react-router-redux application going on where `/home` has a button which when clicked should navigate to `/profile` page. Currently my code looks like this.

actions/index.js

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import * as actionTypes from '../constants'

const homeClicked = () => {
  return { type: actionTypes.HOME_CLICK }
}

const profileClicked = () => {
  return { type: actionTypes.PROFILE_CLICK }
}

export const handleHomeClick = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(homeClicked())
    dispatch(push('/profile'))
  }
}

export const handleProfileClick = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(profileClicked())
    dispatch(push('/'))
  }
}
```

containers/HomeContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../actions'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Home extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.handleHomeClick();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Home'>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Home</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Home.propTypes = {
  handleHomeClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {}
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Home))
```

containers/ProfileContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../actions'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Profile extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.handleProfileClick();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Profile'>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Profile</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Profile.propTypes = {
  handleProfileClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {}
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Profile))
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { HOME_CLICK, PROFILE_CLICK } from '../constants'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

const clickReducer = (state={ message: 'HOME' }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
  case HOME_CLICK:
    return { message: 'PROFILE' };
  case PROFILE_CLICK:
    return { message: 'HOME' };
  default:
    return state
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  clicking: clickReducer,
  routing: routerReducer
})
```

constants.js

```
export const HOME_CLICK = 'HOME_CLICK'
export const PROFILE_CLICK = 'PROFILE_CLICK'
```

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export default createBrowserHistory()
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createRoutes from './routes'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import browserHistory from './history'
import reduxLogger from 'redux-logger'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';

const middlewares = applyMiddleware(
  thunk, 
  routerMiddleware(browserHistory), 
  reduxLogger
);
const store = createStore(rootReducer, middlewares)

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

const routes = createRoutes(history)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    {routes}
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router'
import HomeContainer from './containers/HomeContainer'
import ProfileContainer from './containers/ProfileContainer'

const createRoutes = (history) => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={HomeContainer}/>
        <Route path='/profile' component={ProfileContainer}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default createRoutes
```

app.js

```
import express from 'express'
import config from './config'
import path from 'path'

const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('*', (req, resp) => {
  resp.render('index');
})

app.listen(config.port, config.host, () => {
  console.info('Server listening to', config.serverUrl())
})
```

This code is changing the url but not rendering the profile page when the `home` button on the home page is clicked. Also here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maXJ5.png) of the picture of redux logger output.

I am stuck on this for a few hours and other SO answers have not been much of a help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be using `react-router-dom`. They still have the `Router` export so you don't have to use `BrowserRouter`.

Comment: Wait a second...you're using `react-router-dom` AND `react-router`?? How would that work? Your `routes.js` uses `react-router`, but the rest of the app uses `react-router-dom`. You should fix the `routes.js` file to use `react-router-dom`.

Comment: If you manually go to `/profile` in the address bar does it work? Is the router working but not the button or is the routing not working at all?

Comment: Yes manually going to the profile link works and it is rendered correctly.

Comment: Clicking the button changes the URL but not the render.

Comment: Perfect, so then you've narrowed it down to an issue with the history object. Can you try using `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router` in your `routes` file?

Comment: No same problem. I have removed `react-router` from every place but still same problem persists.

Comment: You can setup a `history.listen( (location, action) => {} )` function to make sure that history changes are taking place. Then you can debug the `location` and `action` to make sure it's receiving the right inputs.

Comment: I logged the` location` and `action`, and `action` is coming as `undefined` all the time. That can not be right, right? Actually I am new to React and JS in general. So sorry if I sound ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

When you click home it should render the home route as you have it written now? Isn't that what it is supposed to do.

Comment: no look, `handleHomeClick` actually pushes `/profile` so ideally the url should change to `/profile` (which it does) and also render the `ProfileContainer` (which it does not). I agree the naming is kind of confusing, but the `home` button actually redirects to `/profile`